# How to reference primary key when inserting in MySQL

Tags: join

I have a database containing the tables `authors` and `books`.

I don't know how to correctly assign the foreign key in the `books` table. I read the information provided in [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) and have constructed my DDL queries as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists authors(
-> author_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
-> name VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE if not exists books(
-> book_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
-> title VARCHAR(255),
-> genre VARCHAR(30),
-> FOREIGN KEY(author_id) REFERENCES authors(author_id)
);
```

Is this the correct way to create a foreign key relationship between my `authors` and `books` tables?

Comment: Yes but you need to specify the column `author_id` as well in `CREATE TABLE books`, not just the FK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the column itself, so the books table should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists books
( book_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
, title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
, genre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
, author_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL

,    FOREIGN KEY(author_id) REFERENCES authors(author_id)
);
```

I added NOT NULL on columns title and genre since I believe they are mandatory in most situations.

I would say that you also need something that uniquely identifies an author in real life, let's assume name does:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists authors
( author_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
, name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Now you can insert a new book like:

```
INSERT INTO books (title, genre, author_id)
SELECT 'The Shining', 'Horror', author_id
FROM authors
WHERE name = 'Stephen King';
```